# How do I use get_adjacent_post_rel_link() in AJAX content loading?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

**[pictures of interface](http://vvcap.net/db/6gl3glIwxhYxU8OJ_oKt.htp)**
I've created a jquery script to AJAX load content.  This content consists of post made from a custom-post-type.  For reference I've used [Loading WordPress posts with Ajax and jQuery](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/04/01/loading-wordpress-posts-with-ajax-and-jquery/).

**Problem** What would I replace the .load URL with, to allow that everytime I click #ajaxNext it goes to previous post submitted custom-post-type URL?

example:  Current displayed custom-post was posted in Aug 30 2011.  *Upon clicking #ajaxNext post updates to Aug 24 2011's post *

[Reference to Wordpress doc.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post_rel_link)
**[jQuery](http://vvcap.net/db/zlUKZgt40ATEAn_CP2z8.htp)** This code is held in the header of single-custom_type.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $("#ajaxNext").click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel")
        $("#container").html("loading...");
        $("#container").load("<?php get_adjacent_post_rel_link( $title, $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous ); ?>");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This `$("#container").load('<?php get_adjacent_post_rel_link( $title, $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous ); ?>');` is what creates the request's URL (I put in a direct URL for testing purposes *and it works. Unfortunately, this php doesn't work*).  I would like that .load's URL to be the next post in wordpress.  I've followed the tutorial as far as it would take me.  Had to make a few adjustments due to me using a custom-post-type.  Still no luck in it working :(

**[PHP](http://vvcap.net/db/n12aaNhlg6paCjJDDUbv.htp)** *Logically home.php contains PHP reference below*

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">
        <div id="inner">
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                  the_post_thumbnail(full);
                } 
            ?>

        </div>
</div>
```

**[HTML](http://vvcap.net/db/6J_hUAm_MIYewDyN3lBN.htp)** *this particular chunk of html contains the anchor which executes the AJAX call*

```
    <section class="summary">
  <div>
    <header> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/works.png"  />
      <h1>Process</h1>
      <h2><a id="ajaxNext" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Next</a></h2>
    </header>
    <p>
      <p><?php getCustomField('Process'); ?></p>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

If i'm missing anything please don't hesitate to ask! I'll respond immediately.

Lastly, If there was a previous button and if the code is drastically different how would i create that .load(); URL request i.e go to the newest post.

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post maybe they can help.

Comment: I still not having very much luck making it work :( I've updated code

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function. `get_adjacent_post_rel_link()` returns a complete link-- `<link rel="prev"...>` You need to raw URL, not the whole link. Unfortunately, there isn't a 'right' function that I can find, much to my surprise. There are [a number of solutions](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/nextpreviews-post-url-only?replies=7) for this out there, but I'd tend to just suck the URL out of what I had.

```
$next = get_adjacent_post_rel_link();
preg_match('/href=\'([^\']*)\'/',$next,$matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```